# Initializing arrays - Warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, variable-assignment

I've already searched for the right answer in several threads, but I couldn't find the exact problem that I have anywhere:
In my program, I've created an array which I'd like to fill with certain dates within a loop. The problem is the assignment - as I don't really know how to describe it (I've got absolutely no experience in programming with C), I'll post a bit of the code:

int *array[] = malloc (w*h*sizeof(int));

array[i] = (SDL_MapRGB(fmt, red, green, blue));

So the first line creates my array and in the second line, I actually wanted to write the result of the function "SDL_MapRGB", which is an integer, in the i-th place in this array. (As this is part of the loop, at the end of it, I would have the whole array filled if it works.)

And this is the error I'm getting:
error: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror]

Does anybody know how I could fix that? I still (after reading in old threads) don't understand what that means. I would be very grateful for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your declaration is wrong. `int *array[]` is an array of pointers. Since you use a one-dimensional array, all you have to do is `int *array`, i. e. drop the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

`array[i]` is a pointer while the function `SDL_MapRGB()` returns an integer which is the reason for the warning.

Change your array declaration to:

```
int *array = malloc (w*h*sizeof(int));
```